# Can I get the RGB of a system color in C# without using pinvoke?

Tags: c#, windows, systemcolors

I want to determine the RGB color of a system color such as SystemColors.HotTrack.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to using P/Invoke and GetSysColor (not including drawing into a bitmap and checking pixel values)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
byte r = SystemColors.HotTrack.R;
byte g = SystemColors.HotTrack.G;
byte b = SystemColors.HotTrack.B;
```

or

```
int argb = SystemColors.HotTrack.ToArgb();
```

Comment: Aw heck. I tried that, but for some reason thought it didnt work - a problem with some other code I think. :)