# WPF - How to use SystemColor in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, systemcolors

I want to use the systemcolor in my design that is used for the hover state of a button.  In my image below, you can see the light blue color that is displayed when the user hovers above the "Find and Replace" button.  I want to set this color programmatically, so I am trying to set the color from C#.  However, when I try to [get the RGB values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317120/can-i-get-the-rgb-of-a-system-color-in-c-sharp-without-using-pinvoke) from `SystemColors.Highlight` the color is wrong.  You can see the color used on the "Projects" button below.

[image: Highlight SystemColor compared to displayed highlight color]

```
byte r = SystemColors.Highlight.R;
byte g = SystemColors.Highlight.G;
byte b = SystemColors.Highlight.B;
```

Comment: Why are you getting rgb values in the first place? what about the alpha value (transparency)? does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276813/cast-color-name-to-solidcolorbrush

Comment: You should use the WPF [SystemColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class and use for example either the `HighlightColor` or the `HighlightBrush` property. Be aware however that the ControlTemplate of the Button does by default not use the Background color for visualizing the "mouse over" state.

Comment: @Clemens your right, it looks like it uses the BorderBrush property

```<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>```

Comment: @Clemens I still can't figure out how to replicate this behavior from binding to the ViewModel.  I'm trying ```BorderBrush="{Binding HighlightColor}"```  However,  I don't know what the property type should be.  Is it a `Color` or a `SolidColorBrush` ?  Then, I don't know how to recreate the Color even with a known hexadecimal.  `"#FF3C7FB1"`

Comment: As the name implies, BorderBrush is a Brush, not a Color. Bind it to a view model property of type Brush or use a value like SystemColors.HighlightBrush.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnUp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0,0,0));
```

try this.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).